# In android, how to set maxwidth of one view to that of an imageview(actually, the image it contains) using xml?

Tags: android, xml, view, width

In android, how to set maxwidth of one view  to that of another, say an imageview(actually, the image it contains) using xml ?

Comment: Hm maybe with a RelativeLayout, but I'm not sure..

Comment: I have a an ImageView which uses a background image. I want to place another control that has the same dimensions as the imagecontrol(both dx and dy). How could this be done?